# Amazon S3 how to control download(get) file with node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, multer-s3

In my node app I need to allow just some user to be able to download files...

How can I do it with amazon S3?

I am using MulterS3 for upload:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3

Which ACL should I use in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to review [S3 bucket policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

an example of policy to grant Read-Only Permission to any User

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

so in your case you want to limit the users who can download so you need to adjust the `Principal` and list who can access. You can check [Specifying a Principal in a Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html) for the different possibilities to list the users.

Comment: Could I put on start access to file private for ACL and then when user is logged to check is thet user allowed to download if he is then app show get access to file? Also could you show me some example? Thanks